# Array contains x and others

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to determine whether an array contains a specific value and other values?

```
array = [1, 1, 3, 4]

array.include? 1 #=> true
```

I can use `include?` to determine if it contains the number `1`, but after that, how do I check if it contains values other than `1`, not caring what those values are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the number of elements with the occurrences of your `1`:

```
array = [1, 1, 3, 4]
p array.count(1) == array.size #true if only 1 are in array (or empty)
p array.count(1) != array.size #True if other values are available,
```

Comment: Your returned value is backwards. You need to use `!` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a number of ways to better answer this question, but without understanding the broader context of how you're using this information, it's difficult to give a precise answer.

That being said, you have a lot of options. I'm not sure there's a single operation you can do to test this, but a clever solution may be something like:

```
array.chunk {|v| v == 1 }.to_a.length == 2
```

What this'll do is return an array of block results and values which match those block results. If the length of that array is 2, then you know that the array has both values which match and don't match `1`.

This is Θ(n), though; you can achieve faster solutions with multiple pieces of code, such as:

```
array.include?(1) && array.any? {|v| v != 1}
```

Comment: I would have written it `array.any?{ |i| i == 1 } && array.any?{ |i| i != 1 } # => true` but according to a benchmark `include?` makes it 50% faster.

Comment: The second one is not only faster, it expresses the problem in a very easy to read way.

Comment: @theTinMan Any time you can avoid block binding and invocation you're going to see speed improvements, generally.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method as

```
def any_other_value_present? number, array
  !!(array - [ number ]).empty?
end
```

Comment: `[array - [ number ])` should be `(array - [ number ])`

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks.. Overlooked

Answer (score 1):

Here are some benchmarks:

```
require 'fruity'

array = [1, 1, 3, 4]

compare do
  chunk_it { array.chunk {|v| v == 1 }.to_a.length == 2 }
  include_and_any { array.include?(1) && array.any? {|v| v != 1} }
  set_diff { !!(array - [ 1 ]).empty? }
  array_count { array.count(1) == array.size }
  partition_them { has_one,and_others = array.partition{|n| n == 1}.map(&:any?); has_one && and_others }
end

# >> Running each test 16384 times. Test will take about 5 seconds.
# >> array_count is faster than include_and_any by 4x ± 0.1 (results differ: false vs true)
# >> include_and_any is faster than set_diff by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0% (results differ: true vs false)
# >> set_diff is faster than partition_them by 2x ± 0.1 (results differ: false vs true)
# >> partition_them is faster than chunk_it by 5x ± 1.0
```

Notice that a couple of them return results that aren't like the others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fairly simple iterator to accomplish this task. For example,

```
array = [1,1,3,4]
puts array.any? { |val| 1 != val }
=> true
```

So this will return true if there is anything other than `1` in your array

Comment: That's not going to work for an array of numbers, as in the OP's example.

Comment: Good point. I changed to a different method of iterating so it will work now.

Comment: why not use `all?` instead of `!=` e.g. `array.all? {|val| val == 1}` since `all?` is the inverse of `any?`

Comment: Something like that would probably work as well though I haven't tried it myself and I don't think I've ever used `all?`. As you can see from the variety of answers, there is always more than one way to do it.

Comment: `all?` isn't the inverse of `any?`. `any?` stops checking once there is a single match. `all?` has to walk the entire array to check every element. There can be a huge difference in speed between the two.

Comment: This doesn't give a valid answer if the array has no `1` elements. It only looks for non-`1`.

Comment: @tinman I was under the impression thats what the OP wanted. He already knows how to check if it has 1 in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 2 booleans I would do this

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
has_one,and_others = a.partition{|n| n == 1}.map(&:any?)
has_one
#=> true
and_others
#=> true
a = [1,1,1,1,1]
has_one,and_others = a.partition{|n| n == 1}.map(&:any?)
has_one
#=> true
and_others 
#=> false
```

`#partition` will separate the array into 2 arrays first being the block is true and second being the block is false.

Answer (score 0):

How About:

```
class Array

def include_any?(*args)
    args.each {|value| return true if include?(value) }
    return false
end

def includes?(*args)
    args.each {|value| return false unless include?(value)}
    return true
end
end


myarray = [:dog, :cat, :cow, :sheep]

#This Will Check if includes all the values given
myarray.includes?(:dog, :cat)
=> true

myarray.includes?(:dog, :horse)
=> false

# This will check if include any of the values given
myarray.includes_any?(:dog, :cat, :horse)
=> true

myarray.includes_any?(:horse, :ox)
=> false
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I reran @theTinMan's benchmark with a different array and four more methods shown below: `index`, `uniq`, `delete` and `dup_delete`. Note `delete` mutates the array.

The results varied quite a bit from run-to-run, but `include_and_any` generally still wins by a comfortable margin.  Also, note that `fruity` (which I've not used previously) reports that it will take several minutes to complete some runs, but in fact never takes more than about 15 seconds.

```
require 'fruity'

def run_em(array, val)
  compare do
    chunk_it        { array.chunk {|v| v == val }.to_a.length == 2 }
    include_and_any { array.include?(val) && array.any? {|v| v != 1} }
    set_diff        { !!(array - [ val ]).empty? }
    array_count     { array.count(val) == array.size }
    partition_them  { has_one,and_others = array.partition{|n| n == 1}.map(&:any?)
                      has_one && and_others }
    index           { !!(array.index(val) && array.index { |e| e != val }) }
    uniq            { a = array.uniq; a.include?(val) && (a.size > 1) }
    delete          { !!array.delete(val) && array.any? }
    dup_delete      { a = array.dup; !!a.delete(val) && a.any? }
  end
end
```

**Test Arrays**

```
n = 1_000
only_dups = Array.new(n,0)
all_dups_but_one = only_dups.dup
all_dups_but_one[n/2] = 1
```

**Only duplicates**

*Only duplicates, first run*

```
run_em(only_dups, 0)

Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 9 minutes.
include_and_any is faster than delete by 2x ± 1.0
delete is similar to index
index is faster than uniq by 2x ± 0.1
uniq is similar to array_count (results differ: false vs true)
array_count is faster than dup_delete by 3x ± 1.0 (results differ: true vs false)
dup_delete is faster than set_diff by 2x ± 0.1 (results differ: false vs true)
set_diff is similar to partition_them (results differ: true vs false)
partition_them is faster than chunk_it by 7x ± 1.0
```

*Only duplicates, second run*

```
run_em(only_dups, 0)

Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 13 seconds.
include_and_any is similar to delete
delete is similar to index
index is faster than uniq by 2x ± 1.0
uniq is similar to array_count (results differ: false vs true)
array_count is faster than dup_delete by 3x ± 1.0 (results differ: true vs false)
dup_delete is faster than set_diff by 2x ± 0.1 (results differ: false vs true)
set_diff is similar to partition_them (results differ: true vs false)
partition_them is faster than chunk_it by 7x ± 1.0
```

**All duplicates but one**

*All duplicates but one, first run*

```
run_em(all_dups_but_one, 0)

Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 4 minutes.
include_and_any is faster than index by 2x ± 1.0
index is similar to delete
delete is similar to uniq
uniq is faster than array_count by 2x ± 0.1
array_count is faster than dup_delete by 2x ± 0.1
dup_delete is faster than set_diff by 2x ± 0.1
set_diff is faster than partition_them by 2x ± 0.1
partition_them is faster than chunk_it by 6x ± 1.0
```

*All duplicates but one, second run*

```
run_em(all_dups_but_one, 0)

Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 12 seconds.
include_and_any is faster than index by 2x ± 1.0
index is similar to delete
delete is similar to uniq
uniq is faster than array_count by 2x ± 1.0
array_count is faster than dup_delete by 2x ± 1.0
dup_delete is faster than set_diff by 2x ± 0.1
set_diff is similar to partition_them
partition_them is faster than chunk_it by 6x ± 1.0
```